# Android GCM error. Server returns Not Registered when client IS registered

Tags: android, cloud, messaging

I followed the demo given at http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html and got a trial application, GCMTrial to work correctly.

But, i tried to follow the same steps on an existing application but it didnot work. So I made an entirely new project. But even then , following the same exact steps, I couldnt get GCM to send a message successfully. So I tried renaming GCMTrial to the required name, and not that too does not work.

I register for GCM via the main activity and get the following log :

```
12-19 21:30:13.102: V/GCMRegistrar(15889): Registering receiver
12-19 21:30:13.112: D/GCMBaseIntentService(15889): handleRegistration: registrationId =         XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, error = null, unregistered = null
12-19 21:30:13.112: D/GCMRegistrar(15889): resetting backoff for com.XXX.XXX
12-19 21:30:13.117: V/GCMRegistrar(15889): Saving regId on app version 1
```

But when i try to send a GCM message, it returns the following error

```
[ errorCode=NotRegistered ]
```

Client Code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TextView tve;
String TAG = "GCMTrial";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
    final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
    if (regId.equals("")) {
        GCMRegistrar.register(this, "XXXXXX");
        Log.v(TAG, "Reg");
    } else {
        Log.v(TAG, "Already registered");
    }
}

GCMIntentService : 
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {
@Override
protected void onError(Context arg0, String arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("GCM", "RECIEVED A MESSAGE");
    // Get the data from intent and send to notificaion bar
}
@Override
protected void onRegistered(Context arg0, String arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
@Override
protected void onUnregistered(Context arg0, String arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

}

Manifest :

Server Code :

```
System.out.println("Sending GCM");
    String key = "XXX"; //Server API key taken from the site
    clientID = "XXXXXXXXX"; // copied from the logs
    Sender sender = new Sender(key);
    Message message = new Message.Builder().build();
    Result result = sender.send(message, clientID, 1);
    System.out.println(result.toString());
```

It is driving me crazy.. It shows as registered in the android phone, even calls the onRegistered method of the GCMIntentService class.. but when i try to send a message, it flags a "NotRegistered Error" ...
I dont know what im doing wrong.. please help me out guys....

Comment: I have no idea what was happening.
But, I reinstalled the GCM extras for android, created a whole new application again, and this time it works!! :)
I did use
    MulticastResult result = sender.send(message, devices, 5);
instead of  Result result = sender.send(message, clientID, 1);
dunno if that was the problem, but it works now...!

Comment: I think the reason why your getting it works after re installing because you already claim a new Reg ID.

Answer (score 11):

Well, know it's a current bug when installing with adb.

GCMRegistrar does not know that the device is unregistered on GCM server and don't register.

What you can do is to register anyway :

```
if (regId.equals("")) {
        GCMRegistrar.register(this, "XXXXXX");
        Log.v(TAG, "Reg");
    } else {
        //I SAY BULLSHIT !
        GCMRegistrar.register(this, "XXXXXX");
        Log.v(TAG, "Reg");
    }
```

Or uninstal the app on client then run a new install from Adb.

Keep in mind there is few chances it happens in production.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to add the constructor in your `GCMIntentService`

add the following to your `GCMIntentService`

```
public GCMIntentService(){
        super(SENDER_ID);
    }
```

SENDER_ID is the XXXXXXX that used to register your app.

Comment: I tried that.. The server keeps sending back a "NotRegistered" Error..... Any other suggestions????

Comment: In my case ,I added the sender_ID that provided to me by google to the request that sent from server. But I used ASP.Net to send the request.

Comment: Its for not SENDER_ID , it the name of THREAD and does necessary to be SEND_ID it could be any string.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to replace the context "this" to "getApplicationContext()" to use the application context. Here is my sample code:

```
private void registerGCM() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1) {
        //prevent crash caused by no google account or not support for gcm
        try {
            GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("test", "!!!cgm " + e.toString());
            return;
        }
    }

    final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(regId)) {
        String gcmSenderId = PreferencesUtil.getStringPreference(PreferencesUtil.SETTING_GCM_SENDER_ID,
                "", getApplicationContext());
        GCMRegistrar.register(getApplicationContext(), gcmSenderId);
    }
    mGCMRegisted = true;
}
```