# FCM Not Registered Error

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented FCM notifications in my project but after a certain period of time client stops receiving notifications. What could be the reason? I am not getting it. Same code works perfectly fine on our server and notifications are received even after a month.

Client starts receiving "Not Registered" error after few days on his devices. He currently has around 1500+ devices registered in his database but after he sends notification ~300 devices have "Not Registered" error and henceforth script deletes them from database.

P.S.: I have gone through all related questions and threads but couldn't find solution. I have referred these links:

[Google Link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-gcm/y8M6ChLB-2E)
[Related StackOverflow Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13956677/android-gcm-error-server-returns-not-registered-when-client-is-registered)
[Related StackOverflow Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919668/google-android-gcm-notregistered-error)
Very much similar like this(although he is doing with cordova plugin):
[another issue](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/104)

Comment: Hi buddy,Are you Using GCM or FCM

Comment: FCM but as we know underlying infrastructure is of gcm. Hence I went in complete depth. Thanks for quick reply @Vadivel

Comment: I doubt there is enough information to answer here. What is the source of the "Not Registered" error? Have you reproduced this issue on a device under your control? What do the logs/stacktraces give you? Have you narrowed it down to a version of Android, or a particular brand/model of device?

Comment: Check your project is avilable or not in FCM .Check database device_id field size.is size is small you get 'not register' error.FCM have option to test your notification

Comment: Actually, I used 10 devices at my office to test the application. Only reason for NotRegistered error is when app is uninstalled. But I am getting this error on live server. Everytime client sends a notification ~300-500 records are deleted due to NotRegistered error. Thanks for quick reply @halfer

Comment: I am storing token as fcm_regid in my database and they are not small @Vadivel Yes project is there on FCM because devices receive notifications for few days but then they stop receiving

Comment: If they may give any limitation for notification

Comment: AFAIK it is free of charge without any limitation

Comment: can you list device model which is not get roken

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129058/discussion-between-rushi-m-thakker-and-vadivel).

Comment: Have you found any solution, as I am also facing the the same issue. Any help from your side will be appreciated.

Comment: no @Jyoti we actually cancelled working on that project. Everything was going great in testing phase but error kept coming for live application.